# Why do I have an unexpected token import when lazy loading?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lazy-loading

I want to do code splitting with lazy loading an i have watched a lot of tutorials with this method and they had no problem, why do I get an unexpected token import and how do i fix it?

React version 16.6.3

```
import PasswordUpdate from '../containers/ResetPassword/PasswordUpdate';
import Main from './Main';
import ChoosePassword from '../../PatientsMain/choosePassword';
import PatientMain from '../../PatientsMain/PatientMain';
import NoMatch from '../components/Exception/404/NoMatch';
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
const Product = lazy(() => import('./ProductHandler'));
```

The last line displays parsing error, unexpected token Import

Comment: js unexpected token problem usually means file not found and get a 404. Check the devtool network panel, look for the request to get that module, check the url and response. If i guess it right, response is a html 404 page, and url is wrong path.

Comment: Very likely you didn't config `publicPath` correctly in webpack.

Comment: @Sven Brodersen did you figure out what was causing the issue?

Comment: Needs babel dynamic import